# Matlab: Return input value with the highest output from a custom function

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I have a vector of numbers like this:

```
myVec= [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...]
```

and I have a custom function which takes the input of one number, performs an algorithm and returns another number.

```
cust(1)= 55, cust(2)= 497, cust(3)= 14, etc.
```

I want to be able to return the number in the first vector which yielded the highest outcome.

My current thought is to generate a second vector, `outcomeVec`, which contains the output from the custom function, and then find the index of that vector that has `max(outcomeVec)`, then match that index to `myVec`. I am wondering, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: No, there is not. If you have access to your black box function you can optimize the approach depending on the algorithm inside it, otherwise it is the only approach you can do.

Comment: Do you have any a priori information on the customized function?

Answer (score 0):

What you described is a good way to do it.

```
outcomeVec = myfunc(myVec);
[~,ndx] = max(outcomeVec);
myVec(ndx) % input that produces max output
```

Another option is to do it with a loop. This saves a little memory, but may be slower.

```
maxOutputValue = -Inf;
maxOutputNdx = NaN;
for ndx = 1:length(myVec)
    output = myfunc(myVec(ndx));
    if output > maxOutputValue
        maxOutputValue = output;
        maxOutputNdx = ndx;
    end
end
myVec(maxOutputNdx) % input that produces max output
```

Those are pretty much your only options.

You could make it fancy by writing a general purpose function that takes in a function handle and an input array. That method would implement one of the techniques above and return the input value that produces the largest output.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the range of discrete numbers you are searching over, you may find a solution with a golden section algorithm works more efficiently. I tried for instance to minimize the following:

```
bf = -21;
f =@(x) round(x-bf).^2;
```

within the range [-100 100] with a routine based on a [script](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25919-golden-section-method-algorithm/content/golden_section_method/golden.m) from the Mathworks file exchange. This specific file exchange script does not appear to implement the golden section correctly as it makes two function calls per iteration. After fixing this the number of calls required is reduced to 12, which certainly beats evaluating the function 200 times prior to a "dumb" call to `min`. The gains can quickly become dramatic. For instance, if the search region is  [-100000 100000], golden finds the minimum in 25 function calls as opposed to 200000 - the dependence of the number of calls in golden section on the range is logarithmic, not linear.

So if the range is sufficiently large, other methods can definitely beat `min` by requiring less function calls. Minimization search routines sometimes incorporate such a search in early steps. However you will have a problem with convergence (termination) criteria, which you will have to modify so that the routine knows when to stop. The best option is probably to narrow the search region for application of `min` by starting out with a few iterations of golden section.

An important caveat is that golden section is guaranteed to work only with unimodal regions, that is, displaying a single minimum. In a region containing multiple minima it's likely to get stuck in one and may miss the global minimum. In that sense `min` is a sure bet.

Note also that the function in the example here rounds input `x`, whereas your function takes an integer input. This means you would have to place a wrapper around your function which rounds the input passed by the calling golden routine.

Others appear to have used genetic algorithms to perform such a search, although I did not research this.